# Search for a pattern in a file and print it in jruby

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, jruby-java-interop

I have a file with n number of lines. I need to search for a field(**SessionId and its value**) in it and print its corresponding value.

I have coded to access the file and print it line by line. Need help in getting a field and printing its value.

Sample lines of file:

```
LastSessionTeardown.cc|598|Resolving:=N2BBSessionGateway.Factory
2013-12-23 06:03:22.488046 UTC VZ_QIP_S3_208 LastSessionTeardown.cc|636 <ERROR>:Failed     to resolve SessionGateway:N2BBSessionGateway.Factory
Cause : user exception, ID 'IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0'
2013-12-23 06:03:22.488078 UTC VZ_QIP_S3_208 LastSessionTeardown.cc|640|Total resolved     SessionGateways list(size):=0
2013-12-23 06:03:22.488098 UTC VZ_QIP_S3_208 LastSessionTeardown.cc|642|Out     resolveSGWs::
2013-12-23 06:07:17.485959 UTC VZ_QIP_S3_208 StreamServiceMasterImpl.cc|989|In     createStream::=77D23ECC4649571A367E9C314C4AA7AA
2013-12-23 06:07:17.487706 UTC VZ_QIP_S3_208 StreamServiceMasterImpl.cc|1036|StreamId:     77D23ECC4649571A367E9C314C4AA7AA  **SessionId: C0A800F0DB2A::1387778933::1501** ContentId: vault22_12.mpg 1xGoid: 
2013-12-23 06:07:17.505233 UTC VZ_QIP_S3_208 StreamServiceMasterImpl.cc|989|In     createStream::=E30CC868325B51D288A8E2D95322B840
```

Note : the file has lots of lines above and below the field specified

Code:

```
require "java"

include_class "java.io.BufferedReader"
include_class "java.io.FileReader"
include_class "java.lang.String"

fileReader = FileReader.new "protocoltiming.log.txt"

bufferReader = BufferedReader.new fileReader
str = bufferReader.readLine

while str
puts str.to_s
str = bufferReader.readLine
 end
```

Kindly help me on what to be added to this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while str
  str = bufferReader.readLine
  session_id = str.strip.scan(/SessionId: (.+)\s/)[0][0] if str.include?("SessionId: ")
  if session_id
    # session_id found
  else
    # session_id not found
  end
end
```

There is actually no need to loop through the lines. You can just read the file and use regular-expression to find required text. But whatever suits your cat. Sometimes reading whole file could be really problematic if it is too big.

HTH

Comment: Thanks but i get this error wen i add the above lines to my code C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:99 warning: already initialized constant String
NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass
  (root) at C:\FCSFinal\latest_Automation\Proj\file.rb:16

Comment: I am not too familiar with `jRuby`, but could you post complete code? Just edit your above post and copy-paste the code you are using.

Comment: Harsh pls find the code, 
require "java"

include_class "java.io.BufferedReader"
include_class "java.io.FileReader"
include_class "java.lang.String"

fileReader = FileReader.new "StreamService.log"

bufferReader = BufferedReader.new fileReader
str = bufferReader.readLine

#puts str.to_s
while str
  str = bufferReader.readLine
  session_id = str.strip.scan(/SessionId: (.+)\s/)[0][0] if str.include?("SessionId: ")
  if session_id
    # session_id found
  else
    # session_id not found
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

done. this works!

```
require "java"

include_class "java.io.BufferedReader"
include_class "java.io.FileReader"
include_class "java.lang.String"

fileReader = FileReader.new "StreamService.log"

bufferReader = BufferedReader.new fileReader

#puts str
str = bufferReader.readLine

while str = bufferReader.readLine
#puts str.to_s

sessionid = ""

  sessionid = str.match(/SessionId:(.*)ContentId/)

  if sessionid.to_s != ''
    puts "Session ID = #{sessionid[1]}"
  end

end
```